# Elementwise multiplication of shorter array with longer one at an offset index with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have 1-D array `a`:

```
[  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.]
```

and a shorter, 1-D multiplication factor array `b` [1, 0.66, 0.33, 0] - which I'd like to use to multiply with the last elements of `a`; so starting, in this case, at index 6 (0-based) of `a`:

```
[                                1.   0.66 0.33 0.]
```

... to obtain:

```
[  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  5.33 3.0  0.0]
```

... basically, a 1-D "fade out". I can do this with normal Python code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
print(a)
# [  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.]

b = np.linspace(1, 0, 4)
print(b)
# [ 1.          0.66666667  0.33333333  0.        ]

# multiply last 4 elements of 'a' element-wise with 'b':
res = []
insertAt = len(a)-len(b) # 6; lendiff
for inda, anum in enumerate(a):
  if inda < insertAt:
    res.append(anum)
  else:
    res.append(anum*b[inda-insertAt])

print(res)
# [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 5.3333333333333339, 3.0000000000000004, 0.0]
```

... but how can I do this in a Numpy vectorized one-liner? I'd like to use something like:

```
res = np.XXX( ... a, ... b, ...)
```

... and get the result, while not changing neither `a` nor `b` in-place, nor doing any superfluous resize operations. Is this possible with numpy? Using an older Numpy v. 1.5.1 here, but answers about newer ones are welcome too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible ways:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1,11)
b = np.linspace(1, 0, 4)
a * np.hstack((np.ones(a.size - b.size), b))
```

Or, which is better from a computational point of view:

```
np.hstack((a[:-b.size], a[-b.size:]*b))
```

It's merely about using the correct indices.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @OliverW. - the `np.hstack` syntax is what I was looking for. Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau Thanks, but Ashwini's answer is definitely also correct (I upvoted).

Answer (score 6):

Take a negative slice of the first array using the length of second array and multiple that slice with second array:

```
>>> arr1 = np.arange(1, 11, dtype=float)
>>> arr2 = np.linspace(1, 0, 4)
>>> res = arr1.copy()
>>> res[-arr2.size:] *= arr2
>>> res
array([ 1.        ,  2.        ,  3.        ,  4.        ,  5.        ,
        6.        ,  7.        ,  5.33333333,  3.        ,  0.        ])
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, @AshwiniChaudhary - this answer is better at pointing out the thinking behind slicing, but I opted to accept the one with the `np.hstack` example. Cheers!